# javax.faces.el.VariableResolver Classcast Exception with SpringBeanFacesELResolver

Tags: spring, jsf

I am trying to upgrade to JSF2 and Spring 3.0.5, I am getting the following error when I deploy to Tomcat.

Any help appreciated.

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver cannot be cast to javax.faces.el.VariableResolver
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:885)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver cannot be cast to javax.faces.el.VariableResolver
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:375)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:225)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver cannot be cast to javax.faces.el.VariableResolver
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.addVariableResolver(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:652)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:305)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigM
```

anager.java:360)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't give too much information but you must have something wrong in your configuration.
Tips:

- Wrong Spring or JSF version or some library is stuck in Tomcat lib. Are you using any kind of dependency management? What is the exact version of your spring-web-xxx.jar? What JSF implementation are you using? What's the version of that one?
- Wrong schemalocation / version in any of your xml config files. Exception suggests the problem is with faces config. It should look like this:

  ```
  <faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
            version="2.0">
  <application>
      <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
  </application>
  ```

You can find some examples [here](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/) and [here](http://www.java-forum.org/646175-post4.html). If you are not able to resolve the issue, please post some of your config files. (appcontext.xml, web.xml, faces-config.xml)

Comment: Thanks that resolved the issue, I needed to change from variable-resolver to el-resolver